# Count duplicated symbols in string and group them using Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, duplicates, grouping

I need to create a function that executes text compression. Function takes one parameter *x* - text and returns text composed of character and it's duplicate count consecutively.

**Example**

*x = "aaavvvfdff"*

**Output**

*a3v3f1d1f2*

I tried this code:

```
const randomText = 'aaavvvfdff'

function getTextCompression(x) {
  const chars = x.split('')

  const duplicatesCount = chars.reduce((count, char) => {
    count[char] = (count[char] || 0) + 1;
    return count;
  }, {});

  console.log(duplicatesCount)
}

getTextCompression(randomText);
```

Getting output: *{ a: 3, v: 3, f: 3, d: 1 }*

Don't know what to do next or is it good aproach?

So how to write a function which returns that output?

Comment: SO isn't a place for "how to" questions. You're supposed to do your own research, and exhaust all available resources. Posting a question here is a last resort, and it must contain an attempt at solving this yourself.

Comment: Use a for loop to iterate your characters in your string, have an integer count value to count if the next character matches the previous character then append this letter and its count to a new string to return, if the next character doesnt match the previous, reset the count and change temp to new character.

Comment: What have you tried already? We can't help you if you don't show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple regular expression and a [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to implement this function, which is a [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding):

```js
function rle (str) {
  return str.replace(/([^])\1*/g, (match, p) => `${p}${match.length}`)
}

let x = 'aaavvvfdff'

console.log(rle(x))
```

Just for fun I'll throw in an inverse function using a similar approach:

```js
function rld (str) {
  return str.replace(/([^])(\d+)/g, (_, p1, p2) => p1.repeat(p2))
}

let x = 'a3v3f1d1f2'

console.log(rld(x))
```